# Actions before Retry on Cypress

Tags: jquery, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

I'm writing a test on Cypress and I want to clear the field values before retries. How should I do it?

```
it('Fill info', { retries: 3 },function () {
    cy
        .get('#name')
        .type('Test')

    cy.intercept('POST', '**/api/**/Find')
        .as('memberresponse')

    cy
        .get('.btn')
        .click()

    cy.wait('@memberresponse').then(xhr => {
        cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body));
        cy.writeFile('***/memberinfo.json', xhr.response.body)
    })
})
```

I want to clear the field value before retry in case of request doesn't pass. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `clear` before typing like this:

```js
it('Fill info', {retries: 3}, function () {
  cy.get('#name').clear().type('Test')

  cy.intercept('POST', '**/api/**/Find').as('memberresponse')

  cy.get('.btn').click()

  cy.wait('@memberresponse').then((xhr) => {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body))
    cy.writeFile('***/memberinfo.json', xhr.response.body)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
cy.get('#name')
  .clear()
  .type('Test')
```

I presume clearing it every run (first or retry) is ok.

Otherwise you could include the page load (cy.visit) in the test.

---

**Action before retry**

I've used this pattern to handle repeating a `before()` hook when retry happens.

You may be able to run your actions there.

```js
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (result) => {
  if (result.currentRetry < result.retries && result.state === 'failed') {
    cy.get('#name')
      .clear() 
  }
})
```