# Inserting data in reloadable field in Cypress script

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to automate my test case in Cypress. I have en input field of text i.e. customer Id. After inserting the customer Id other fields i.e. customer's name, address, telephone etc will be field up automatically if the customer exists in the database. The customer ID that I am using exists in the database and it works fine when I insert the ID manually. But when I run the Cypress script it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
it ('Customer information', () => {  
  cy.get('#ID').click().type('1234567')
})
```

I have even tried with 'enter' but not working.
Is there any idea or any alternative to insert a value which will reload the other fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Actions before Retry on Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73384438/actions-before-retry-on-cypress)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

```js
cy.get('#ID').type('1234567', {force: true})
cy.get('#ID').type('1234567').trigger('change')
```

Comment: Thanks to all for all suggestions. Even my problem doesn't solved I learned a lot :-)

Comment: Thanks to all for all suggestions. Even my problem isn't solved I learned a lot :-) I think I have to check the log and find out the trigger's name.  Trigger, realClick, blur, enter etc lead to reaload the page from the beginning i.e. I have to login again(after Trigger, realClick, blur, enter  command I logged out). Have anyone any clue why I logged out? Or it may be  mistake in the app's code?

Answer (score 0):

The app is designed to fetch the customer for the id that's entered, which means there's an event handler set up to do this.

From [type#Events-that-fire](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Events-that-fire), these events are fired automatically

> The following events will be fired based on what key was pressed identical to the event spec:
>
> - keydown
> - keypress
> - beforeinput
> - textInput
> - input
> - keyup

Also, since you tried `cy.get('#ID').type('1234567{enter}')`, the `change` event is also sent

> Additionally **change events** will be fired either when the {enter} key is pressed

---

#### These steps should help you

**Try blurring the input**

The test should mimic the actions a user takes, but `{enter}` may not trigger the response. Try `cy.get('#ID').type('1234567').blur()`

**Checking for event listeners**

Take a look at the Elements tab / Event Listeners in devtools to see what events are set up on the element.

Use `.trigger()` to fire the events that are listed. Even if they are one the above, still try to fire them after the .type() since there may be a timing issue.

**Check for fetch**

Take a look at the devtools Network tab to see if a fetch is triggered. The `.type()` command may be working but the fetch of customer data failing.

**Switch to cypress-real-events**

Add the package [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealtype) and use

```js
cy.get('#ID').focus()
cy.realtype('1234567{enter}')
cy.get('#ID').trigger(...)     // events found in devtools
```

or

```js
cy.get('#ID').focus()
cy.realtype('1234567').blur()
cy.get('#ID').trigger(...)     // events found in devtools
```